# Get remote file extension

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm creating a mechanism of downloading remote files by URL and I need to generate a correct file name  and extension for a file where to store remove file content. 
To download file I'm going to use guzzle, and I know I can get 'Content-type' header to determine mime type, but how to extract correct extension?

Code:

```
$localPath = '/tmp/'; 
$guzlleClient =new Client();
$request = new Request('get', $url);
$response = $guzzleClient->send($request);

$extension = ??? <--- how can I determine correct extension???
$fileName = $localPath. mt_rand() . $extension;

file_put_content($fileName, $response->getBody());
```

Comment: You'll want to create a lookup array which holds mappings for possible filename extensions based on content-type you might receive, then determine the extension after looking into that array.

Comment: but what if I do not have a strict list of required file types and I expecting any file? Maybe there is some library what can set correct extension from mime?

Comment: I found this one: https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types, but it uses JavaScript. [This](https://github.com/adrienrn/php-mimetyper) uses PHP.

Comment: Thanks I'll try those packages and also I found https://github.com/ralouphie/mimey

Comment: Why not just look it up in the database which is already on the host? (in /etc/mime.types)

Comment: Hmm, I did not know there is such file... Need to check if it exist on alphine docker image

Comment: I do not have /etc/mime.types file in docker image (where project exists) not on my system (mac os). So I think there is not 100% that file will exist on production machines. xz